# Erro ao criar diretório com php mesmo usando o file_exists

Tags: php

Beleza pessoal? Estou com um problema que é o seguinte. Utilizo o seguinte código para criar um diretório.

```
    //verifica se existe diretorio para criar
$dir = 'imagens/'.$id_produto.'/';

if(!file_exists($dir)){
  mkdir($dir, 0777);
}else{
  echo "Erro ao criar diretório";
}
```

Mas mesmo indo la na pasta e deixando ela limpa, executando esse código ele aponta que o diretório existe. Já exibi separadamente `echo file_exists($dir);` e ele me retorna 1 como se existisse o diretório. O estranho é que chegou a funcionar normalmente e agora estou com esse problema. alguma idéia?

Comment: Você já verificou se esse caminho relativo da var "$dir" está mesmo apontando para onde você acha? E quanto as permissões da pasta?

Comment: Esqueci que mudei esse código de pasta e realmente estava criando em outro lugar. Obrigado ai pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Tente isso

`mkdir($dir, 0777, true);`

Comment: Só especifique melhor qual a diferença do seu mkdir para com o dele e o que o 'true' muda no funcionamento do código para que o usuário que perguntou e outros que venham a ver a pergunta entendam melhor sua resposta. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar a função `is_dir` veja em http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

remova a última concatenação na váriavel `$dir`, segue exemplo abaixo.

```
$dir = 'imagens/'.$id_produto;
if(!is_dir($dir)){
   mkdir($dir, 0777,true);
    // verifica novamente
    if (!is_dir($dir)){
        echo "erro ao criar";
    } else{ 
        echo "dir criado agora ".time();
    }
}else{
    echo "dir existe";
}
```